# Trello: How can a board be copied including all activities/comments?

Tags: trello-boards

As I copy the boards with the standard Trello function, the comments/activities are not copied with it. Only the board itself, the tasks, attachments and tags are copied but the comments not. Does anybody know whether I have overseen something or is Trello still working on this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, actions and comments are not preserved on copied boards by design - since copy is not meant as a way to back up boards so much as to create and use template boards.

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks very much for your comment. It's a pitty but I understand what you are saying about the functionality itself. What I wanted to do is transfer an existing board to a newly created organisation which also contains its (new) boards. I guess that cannot be done other than using the copy function which again results in losing my comments right? If you have a workaround or the correct function, please let me know!

Comment: You should be able to move the board between organizations using settings -> change organization. Does that help?

Comment: brett, you are my personal hero! I am utmost thankful for your help. Where are you from? I am in Vienna (Austria). If you come over, let me know, send me your mail so that I can thank you, honestly ;-)

Comment: @Pedro Wow, thanks! I'm on the Trello team, here in New York.

Comment: hi brett, so you are at trello directly. then great compliments on trello. it has become our perfect orga tool, used internally as well as externally with freelancers we work together with. we have just cut down other tools to reorganize everything on trello cause it's so powerful and simple at the same time. would you send me your mail so i can contact you in case we have other problems and also to let you know how you can contact me if you do ever come over?